# Is Geotag Location Sent for iMessage Photos?

Tags: messages, ios

When I send a photo to a friend via iMessage and not MMS, will the geotag location be sent along with the photo? If so, is there any way to remove the location before the photo is sent for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The location data is definitely sent with images sent over iMessage; I've saved an image sent by another person and itappeared on the "Places" tab in Photos. A trick you could use to remove the location data is to open the picture, take a screenshot (press home and sleep together) and then send the screenshot. The downside though is that it might be lower quality.

Comment: They definitely should give some sort of option to remove the location data from photos in iMessage. Just in case Apple is reading this.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug/feature (at least in iOS 10.0.2) that prevents the geotag being applied when you take a photo from within iMessage. (You click the camera icon within iMessage and take a new photo.) If you attach a photo from your gallery that has a geotag, it will be sent as usual.